# why the member function mem_fun calls must be a const one?

Tags: c++, mem-fun

`mem_fun` and `mem_fun_ref` and many other member function adaptors can make member functions act like orindinary functions. But there is one restriction that the member function that they call must be a **const** one. I get to know how to use them, but confused and puzzled by the reasons behind it. Why is it designed in this way?

update:
    Sorry for the ambiguity. write an example below.

```
class A
{
    ...
    //void fun(){cout<<"Fun";} This is not const and the compiler would complain
    void fun() const {cout<<"Not fun";}
    ...
}
vector<A> avec;
...
for_each(avec.begin(),avec.end(),mem_fun_ref(&A::fun));
...
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.. can you do an example?

Comment: FWIW, `std::mem_fun` and `std::mem_fun_ref` have been replaced in C++11 by `std::men_fn` and, more generally, by `std::bind`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such a restriction. These template functions are overloaded for const and non-const member functions.

For example

```
template<class S, class T>
mem_fun_t<S,T> mem_fun(S (T::*f)());

template <class S, class T>
const_mem_fun_t<S,T> mem_fun(S (T::*f)() const);
```

Comment: Yoo, you are right. I checked again. Looks like the book is somehow obsolete.